Amazon SES successfully forwarded emails but respond with 451 4.3.0 This message could not be delivered
I have set up a rule set for inbound emails in AWS SES.

Deliver to S3 bucket
Invoke AWS Lambda function
Stop rule set

This rule set successfully forward all my domain emails to my personal gmail account.
However server start to respond to every email with: Delivery Status Notification (Failure)
This message could not be delivered due to a recipient error. Please try again later.
...
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 451 4.3.0 This message could not be delivered due to a recipient error. Please try again later.
Status: 4.3.0

Even if I remove Lambda invocation and Deliver to S3 bucket, still have same error.
How to prevent SES from sending error response?
I seen an old question Amazon SES inbound email delivery failed 4.3.0 451
In my case it's clearly different reason for error.

Answering my own question: configuration works for years, then errors appears. Seems changes made from Amazon side. One strange thing I found - outcoming mails successfully send using an IAM Access key for SES which doesn't belong to this account IAM. Only solution I found - completely recreate SES configuration, S3 bucket, Lambda.
